# While web scraping in BeautifulSoup, how can I refer to a specific <span> tag if it has no class or id?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently new to web scraping in Python with BeautifulSoup and am attempting to gather news articles from the Sudan Tribune for a Human Rights project. The body text is contained in 'span' tags and my end goal is to filter out all articles that do not contain news about killings or HR violations. My question is, how can I refer to a specific body of text when each one is contained in a tag called 'span' with no class or id to differentiate it from the others.

My code so far gets me the links and body text of each article but I don't know how to call a specific one, only all of them at once. Ideally, Id like to be able to quickly refer to a specific article's body text and tell Python to either include it or not based on my own criteria.

```
URL = 'https://www.sudantribune.com/spip.php?rubrique1'
Source = requests.get(URL)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Source.content, 'html.parser')
print("You are current crawling the website -> " + URL)
links = []
for link in Soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
print("The links to the articles from " + URL + " are:")
print("https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[45] + "\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[46] +
"\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[47] + "\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" +
links[48] + "\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[49] + "\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[50]+
"\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[51]+ "\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[52] + "\n" +
"https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[53] + "\n" + "https://www.sudantribune.com/" + links[54])
 Descriptions = Soup.find_all('span')
 print(Descriptions)
```

I have only been working with Python for a week now so any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: You have gathered all span tags in `Descriptions`. You can loop through Descriptions and print the article body using `.text`. e.g. `for desc in Descriptions: print(desc.text)`. Obviously replace `print` with whatever condition you want to check the article body against.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve the span from the different web pages living at different urls? If so, for each url you need to repeat the initial process of 'Getting' the data from that page and investigating.

```
URL = 'https://www.sudantribune.com/spip.php?rubrique1'
Source = requests.get(URL)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Source.content, 'html.parser')
print("You are current crawling the website -> " + URL)
links = []
for link in Soup.find_all('a'):
    SubPage = requests.get("https://www.sudantribune.com/" + link)
    SubSoup = BeautifulSoup(SubSource.content, 'html.parser')
    Descriptions = Soup.find_all('span')
    print(Descriptions)   
    if SOME_CONDITION_YOU_SPECIFY:         
         links.append(link.get('href')) # Only append if it meets your criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to do it, I would do something like this

```py
for story in Soup.find_all("li"):
   span = story.find("span")  # might even be able to do "story.span"
   if is_this_interesting(span.text):
        store_interesting_article(....)
```

Comment: Ahh I think this might be what OP was after, not my solution!

Comment: This is great thank you. I'm able to select the ones I want and Francis Webb's comment expanded the solution so I can apply it to different web pages throughout the site.